# UISearchController landscape orientation layout issue

Tags: ios, swift, landscape, uisearchcontroller

In landscape orientation `UISearchController` getting UI glitch issue. Using Xcode 10.2. There is not built-in *`navigationBar`* used.

**Landscape Preview**

[image]

**Portrait Preview**

[image]

Instance declaration

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

@IBOutlet weak var vwSearch: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var vwSearchHeightConstant: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Initialization in `viewDidload`

```
func setupSerachResultController()
{
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Email"
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor.clear)
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    vwSearch.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
}
```

**Initial Preview**

[image]

**UISearchBarDelegate methods**

```
extension ListViewController: UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {

    }

    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.vwSearchHeightConstant.constant = 100
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
        return true
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.vwSearchHeightConstant.constant = 60
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

> As shown in initial preview there is not scope bar visible so height
>   of `vwSearch` **60**, which managed using `vwSearchHeightConstant` constraint. For scope bar height changed to **100**,  which toggle managed in `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` and `searchBarCancelButtonClicked`.

Any help much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430104/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-misaligns-while-active-during-rotation

Comment: @guru Yes, I go through with that solutions, But here issue is different. The searchBar goes above the customNaviationBar view. And real the  searchBar subview of one view, And that view below that customNaviationBar view.